# (T-SQL) Join two columns to one common column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this problem:

**TABLE1**:

```
|  ID  |  DESCRIPTION  |
|  10  |  Apple        |
|  20  |  Banana       |
|  33  |  Pineapple    |
|  47  |  Orange       |
```

**TABLE2**:

```
|  ID  |  FRUIT1  |  FRUIT2  |
|   1  |    10    |    47    |
|   2  |    47    |    10    |
|   3  |    33    |    20    |
|   4  |    20    |    33    |
```

If I select all data in `TABLE2`, I want in output the name of the fruits (`TABLE1.DESCRIPTION`) for `TABLE2.FRUIT1` and `TABLE2.FRUIT2` and not the ID.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join `table2` twice with different alias name

```
select t2.id, f1.description, f2.description
from table2 t2
left join table1 f1 on f1.id = t2.fruit1
left join table1 f2 on f2.id = t2.fruit2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join back to `Table1` twice; you just need to give different table aliases:

```
SELECT ID, T1a.Description [Fruit1], T1b.Description [Fruit2]
FROM Table2 T2
INNER JOIN Table1 T1a
  ON T2.Fruit1 = T1a.ID
INNER JOIN Table1 T1b
  ON T2.Fruit1 = T1b.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a union to combine the columns together like this:

```
Select t1.Description
from Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1 on t1.ID = t2.Fruit1
UNION
Select t1.Description
from Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1 on t1.ID = t2.Fruit2
```